# Undefine symbol from Qt library

Tags: qt

I create a static library using Qt library. But when I use this created static library and link to my application, then the problem is it will give me undefine symbol of QImage.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

some error message:

```
undefined reference to `QImage::~QImage()'
```

Comment: Makefile? Link command? Anything? One guess would be that you're not linking your app to the Qt library.

Comment: @vanza: so I need to link to Qt library? But my library is already a static so I assume that the Qt library is in my library. Please enlighten me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the application with your library AND Qt libraries.
You library is not linked to Qt.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a a static library, it doesn't pull in everything from QT. It pulls in only the object files to satisfy the undefined symbols.

So you still need to link with QT libraries.